# JQueryUI for GWT

Tags: java, gwt, maven, gquery

I have followed the guide for JQueryUI for GWT in Eclipse, but I get the error:

```
The type com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I'm not quite sure if I'm doing everything correctly, though. I never imported JQueryUI (I have no clue how to import non-jar files correctly), but I think that the Google CDN network takes care of that, no? The tutorial I followed is here:

http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/wiki/GettingStarted

I tried converting my file to Maven by right clicking and choosing convert to maven. This created a POM.xml file. I added this to the pom file:

```
        <repositories>
<repository>
  <id>gwtquery-ui-repository</id>
  <url>http://gwtquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
</repository>
```

```
      <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwtquery-ui</artifactId>
  <version>r146</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have this for JQueryUI part in my.gwt.xml file:

```
<inherits name='gwtquery.plugins.UiGoogleCdn' /> 
<inherits name='gwtquery.plugins.UiEmbedded' />
```

Any tips at all would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my error. You are required to install and setup GWTQuery before you can use GWTQueryUI. I thought it was standalone, but it was not.